# Add user name with pie chart

Tags: asp.net, pie-chart

I am pretty new to pie charts and i have one that displays seconds to hh:mm:ss but I also need the username to be included as well here is my code.

```
   string easystone = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["easystone"].ConnectionString;

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(easystone);
    SqlDataAdapter graph = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT[User] , sum(time) as [time] FROM avgtime3 group by[user]", con);
    DataTable graphdata = new DataTable();
    graph.Fill(graphdata);
    chart1.DataSource = graphdata;
    chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Title = "";
    foreach (DataRow row in graphdata.Rows)
    {
        int total = (int)row["time"];
        int index = chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(row["User"], new object[] { total });
        chart1.Series["Series1"].Points[index].Label = // I need the username to go here.
        chart1.Series["Series1"].Points[index].Label = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", (total / 60) / 60, (total / 60) % 60, total % 60);
    }
```

Comment: Probably you want to show username and time to the label. So prefix the user name along with time. `chart1.Series["Series1"].Points[index].Label = row["User"].ToString() + " : " + string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", (total / 60) / 60, (total / 60) % 60, total % 60);`

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please mark it as answered it may help others who have similar query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prefix the user name along with time.

```
chart1.Series["Series1"].Points[index].Label = row["User"].ToString() + " : " + string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", (total / 60) / 60, (total / 60) % 60, total % 60);
```